# copying iterators and producing combinations

Tags: python, list, iterator, combinations

Say I have a list, and I want to produce a list of all unique pairs of elements without considering the order. One way to do this is:

```
mylist = ['W','X','Y','Z']
for i in xrange(len(mylist)):
    for j in xrange(i+1,len(mylist)):
        print mylist[i],mylist[j]
W X
W Y
W Z
X Y
X Z
Y Z
```

I want to do this with iterators, I thought of the following, even though it doesn't have brevity:

```
import copy
it1 = iter(mylist)
for a in it1:
    it2 = copy.copy(it1)
    for b in it2:
        print a,b
```

But this doesn't even work. What is a more pythonic and efficient way of doing this, with iterators or zip, etc.?

Comment: It is the second time I've seen this homework question today.

Comment: @Apalala, thanks for the downvote, but I actually wanted the answer for something I am coding and I couldn't find any other similar question while searching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has already been done and is included in the standard library as of Python 2.6:

```
import itertools

mylist = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
for pair in itertools.combinations(mylist, 2):
    print pair        # pair is a tuple of 2 elements
```

Seems pretty Pythonic to me ;-)

Note that even if you're calculating a lot of combinations, the `combinations()` function returns an iterator so that you can start printing them right away. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Also, you are referring to the result as a Cartesian product between the list and itself, but this is not strictly correct: The Cartesian product would have 16 elements (4x4). Your output is a subset of that, namely only the 2-element [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) (with repetition not allowed) of the values of the list.

Comment: You're right, I should have called it combinations, which would have probably gotten me the answer!

Answer (score 0):

@Cameron's answer is correct.

I just wanted to point out that

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    do_something_to(mylist[i])
```

is nastily un-Pythonic; if your operation is read-only (does not have to be stored back to the array), do

```
for i in mylist:
    do_something_to(i)
```

otherwise

```
mylist = [do_something_to(i) for i in mylist]
```

Comment: I agree, but I was doing range(len(mylist)) because I needed to refer to the index.

Comment: you can also use enumerate. For example:
"for index, value in enumerate(mylist): print(index, value)"