# Every permutation of list elements (without replacement)

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics

In Python 2.7 I'd like to get the [self-cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/533905/2071807) of the elements of a list, but without an element being paired with itself.

```
 In[]: foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
 In[]: [x for x in itertools.something(foo)]
Out[]: 
       [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]
```

Currently I do:

```
[x for x in itertools.product(foo, repeat=2) if x[0] != x[1]]
```

but I suspect there's a built-in method for this. What is it?

*Note: `itertools.combinations` [wouldn't give me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5267969/2071807) `('a', 'b')` and `('b', 'a')`*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) instead of combinations.

```
from itertools import permutations

foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(list(permutations(foo, 2)))

# Out: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]
```

Comment: The documentation neatly corroborates this by showing that `permutations()` can be implemented in terms of `product()` with repeats removed, exactly what the OP is doing.